# PowerShell "Untrusted Publisher" prompt for Trusted Publisher

Tags: sql-server, powershell, certificate, code-signing

I'm having an issue with PowerShell steps in a SQL Agent job - specifically:

**Problem**

When running a SQL Agent job with a PowerShell step using a Proxy/Credential, the job throws an "AuthorizationManager check failed" exception.

**Detail**

The entirety of the exception is as follows:

```
A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. 
The corresponding line is 'import-module SQLPS -Version 15.0'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. 
The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: 
Microsoft.PowerShell, G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\sqlprovider.types.ps1xml: The file was skipped because of the following validation exception: AuthorizationManager check failed..`
```

I can reproduce this error by running SQLPS.exe in a command prompt running as the Proxy Account:

```
PS Cert:\CurrentUser> sqlps
Microsoft (R) SQL Server (R) PowerShell
Version 15.0.2000.5
Copyright (c) 2019 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

Do you want to run software from this untrusted publisher?
File G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\sqlprovider.format.ps1xml is published by CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=MOPR, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US and is not trusted on your system. Only run scripts from trusted publishers.
[V] Never run  [D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [A] Always run  [?] Help (default is "D"):
```

As you can see, the module and code signing cert in question are components of SQL Server itself.

For reference, the ExecutionPolicy is *AllSigned*.

**Troubleshooting**

First step is to check the signature of that ps1xml file:

```
PS Cert:\CurrentUser\> Get-AuthenticodeSignature "G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\sqlprovider.types.ps1xml"

Directory: G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS

SignerCertificate                         Status                                 Path
-----------------                         ------                                 ----
BC0B6D0D7398035FCFBE8CC1AD8724A23A3A89DB  Valid                                  sqlprovider.types.ps1xml
```

When I browse certs via MMC - the thumbprint corresponds to a Microsoft Code Signing cert - which is expired, but my understanding is that this will only prevent signing, not execution. So I take it a step further and directly compare to the cert store in PowerShell

```
PS Cert:\CurrentUser\> Get-ChildItem -Path "Cert:\*$((Get-AuthenticodeSignature 'G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\sqlprovider.types.ps1xml').SignerCertificate.Thumbprint)" -Recurse

PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::CurrentUser\TrustedPublisher

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
BC0B6D0D7398035FCFBE8CC1AD8724A23A3A89DB  CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=AOC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Wa...

PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\TrustedPublisher

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
BC0B6D0D7398035FCFBE8CC1AD8724A23A3A89DB  CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=AOC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Wa...`
```

And this demonstrates that the cert is in both the current user (Proxy account) and local machine TrustedPublisher stores.

**Questions**

- Why I getting prompted to allow this publisher when a trust ostensibly already exists?
- Does PowerShell maintain some intermediary list of trusts?
- If this prompt is by design, is there a way to indicate an "Always Run" preference non-interactively?

Any assistance or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: On my mobile, but is there a more updated version of the module that would be signed

Comment: I believe the issue is occurring do to a timeout when making a connection between client and server.  There is lot of reasons a timeout will occur.  Often applications report when a timeout like this occurs is do to TLS failing during a connection.  But TLS may not be the real reason for the timeout.

Comment: @alexzelaya - the module in question is signed, and it's a component of SQL Server 2019. I'm reluctant to modify it or overwrite it because it's kind of baked in - ie running (G:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\) SQLPS.exe automatically loads this module. To that end, maybe I'm better off not using SQLPS and just changing my agent jobs over to call native PowerShell instead.

Comment: Technically a code signed executable lives only as long as the code signing certificate that signed it... unless the signature was also timestamped by a CA when the code signing was applied (which is the case for SQLProvider.Types.ps1xml).

Comment: Probably the issue here is that it's a deprecated SHA1 signature instead of SHA2. We stopped supporting SHA1 signatures when we stopped supporting Windows XP. I'm surprised Microsoft, having themselves deprecated SHA1 signatures in 2019, is still distributing things that only have a SHA1 signature and aren't even dual signed with SHA1 and SHA2.

Comment: @jdweng TLS issues do not cause a timeout, they fail immediately. There is no timeout here, nor is there a TLS issue. The issue is the package is not signed properly.

Comment: @Charlieface : What?  This case you are not correct.   A HTTP connection will fail with a timeout and you will not get a response.

Comment: @jdweng If the server doesn't respond then you get a timeout error. If the server responds but the TLS connection fails then you get a TLS error, not a timeout error. Neither of these happened here: the package was downloaded correctly but its signature could not be verified.

Comment: @Charlieface : Not with the NET/CORE libraries.

Comment: @jdweng What are you talking about? What I describe is how it works in Core and Framework, as well as on any other system. timeouts are timeouts, TLS errors are TLS errors, they are unrelated, and both unrelated to verifying a publisher's signature on a Powershell package

Comment: @Charlieface : The TLS errors are timeouts when a connection doesn't complete.  The client does not see any errors.  The TLS checks are done on the server end and the server doesn't response when the check fails.

Comment: @jdweng Not normally. Standard TLS protcol is to close the connection rather than drop it, so the client would get a `RESET` packet, which matches what you see in such cases as a Unexpected End Of Stream error on the client. Either, not relevant as I've said multiple times, and I have nothing more to say on this.